# unexpected Ubuntu 16.04 force shutdown

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shutdown

My Lenovo ThinkPad T470p with Ubuntu 16.04 "randomly" powers off ("pulling the plug" style) when I use it, usually when I type on my keyboard. It looks like there may be a shortcut(?) which causes this, but I can't find it in the Keyboard/Shortcuts settings menu.

Maybe it's connected with the laptop model?

Anyway I would love to find and disable it somehow, can anybody suggest on how to find out what's happening here?

Comment: You must inspect `/var/log/syslog` at exact time when it happened last time. There you'll find  the possible cause. If you prefer, pastebin this file copy for us, please....

Comment: Also run dmesg -T command to examine the system.

Comment: @Redbob What exactly should I look for? I know the shutdown time in a +/- 2 minute scope. Here's a part of the logs which looks suspicious to me:
https://pastebin.com/rCujWBWZ

Comment: Searching for this [Launchpad message](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1464917), I found you can do a debug-shell to inspect real causes to shutdown.  You can read mentioned doc by this command `zcat /usr/share/doc/systemd/README.Debian.gz | more`